# How to use chrome/chromium anonymously and be log in google at the same time

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I need to use chrome/chromium for some reason but I do not want to give any information which could identify my identity to google. But at the same time I need to be logged in google account. Is there any way? I suppose that vpn is not enough...